# Callback Nativescript socialshare on ios

Tags: nativescript

I'm new in nativescript and I have an issue using nativescript-socialshare on ios. After sharing my content, I want to know that I'm returned to my app. In android I've used on resume event, and on tis function i'm navigating to the next view of my app. but in ios, it's not work until I pause the app manually. Thank you for your help!

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: I'm just facing the same issue!

Comment: Post some code you've used using resume event to see if someone can help us

Comment: Have you found a solution by yourself? I think I know how to solve it, if you still need it, I can post an answer.